# Retrive posts thumbnail in original size

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I am trying to integrate a jquery gallery into my wordpress theme.The gallery will have a caption that will display the posts title and excerpt content.

What I am thinking to do is create a custom query for the posts and retrieve the posts thumbnail image aldo I would like to be able to get the image in it's full size that is stored in the media gallery.

Is there a way I can achive this?

Comment: You're asking for thumbnails that don't behave as thumbnails? That's quite paradoxal... Anyway, I believe you are asking for `get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'full');` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like this http://kingsmennigltd.com/ that you want ? it was developed with wordpress and it a plugin that i developed

Comment: I am hoping to stay away for a while from plugins just started to learn wordpress theme development and want to integrate as much functionality in the theme without plugins

Comment: i'm not sure about that, thought the only way you can do that has to be through plugins will do a search on that though and get back you

Comment: Downvoted because the domain is not active anymore, and there is no actual solution in the answer.